# Keep absolute divs always on image parent container

Tags: responsive-design, position, absolute, interactive

Im working on a interactive show room. In this showroom visitors can click on products to get a lichtbox with more info about that product.

See: http://codepen.io/xiniyo/pen/wLoxE

Is it possible to keep the dots always on the same position as the image below when you rescale the browser. Normal width = 1140px minimum width = 960px. Now the imag scales but the dots always stay on their absolute position.

I`ve tried it with % calculations but that didn't work either. The image scales faster than the dots do.

With difficult % calculations? or some Javascript.
Or is it possible to calculate the Absolute position from the canter of the div?

Comment: It should work with percents, you might need to change the dots to smaller dots when the screen size gets too small. Also you can consider using an image instead of bg image. I think bg image with `contain` it might not resize perfectly. See http://www.lexus.ca/lexus/en/automobiles/ls#/technology for example

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i`ll try the lexus style :)

Answer (score -1):

```
position: fixed;
```

This should work